# Laravel 5.3 blade decoding HTML Special Characters

Tags: laravel

I save some HTML Code in my Database. When I got that data to the blade, CSS not working on.

In the Page Source Code I found that < shows as '& lt;'

What method have I to use to convert & lt to <

Is there anybody to help me?

Comment: use `{!!  !!}` insead of `{{  }}`, it will prevent the decoding of html characters. Do note that this can be a security hazard as custom script or css tags could be inserted into the HTML DOM that way

Answer (score 25):

Change your syntax from `{{ }}` to `{!! !!}` that should do the trick

Comment: Worked like magic

Answer (score 9):

Try this: [`html_entity_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)

```
{!! html_entity_decode($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') !!}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
{!! html_entity_decode(nl2br(e($text))) !!}
```

- The `e` function runs `htmlentities` over the given string.
- `nl2br` Inserts HTML line breaks before all newlines in a string
- `html_entity_decode` Convert all HTML entities to their applicable characters

`nl2br(e($text))` and `{!! !!}` was ot enough to convert `&quot;` to "

I used `html_entity_decode` and then it worked exactly how I wanted. I still think it is too much for one simple thing.

Answer (score 2):

use  below code:

`{!! htmlspecialchars($post->description)!!}`

This will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, btw this is useful in this case: `<pre><code>PUT HERE</code></pre>`

Answer (score 1):

In order to `echo` HTML content as code, not as string, you must use the unescape `{!! !!}` syntax in your blade file. But for the issue you are experimenting, you also need to use the `html_entity_decode()` PHP function.

```
{!! html_entity_decode($str) !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, Working with

```
{!! html_entity_decode($logo, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') !!}
```